# \includegraphics with spaces, dots and underscores

Tags: luatex, underscore, includegraphics

I've already tried 10 billion advices like using `\usepackage{grffile}`, wrapping the filename into `{}` and/or `""` (in any combination).
Nothing is working!

So, I have a file with path `plots/task-1/ABC123_/qa_pt:0.20-2.00/VtxZ (-10.00, 10.00)/charged; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/FB: 16; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/eff/eta_phi.pdf` and I need to include it into `beamer` presentation, which is compiled by LuaLaTeX (if it is important).

<s>Changing the path is not an option</s> I can live without spaces (but can't without dots and underscores), but it is better to keep them, and there are multiple files with the same name but different paths which need to be used.

Minimal non-working example (find any .pdf file to include and place it at the path):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics{plots/task-1/ABC123_/qa_pt:0.20-2.00/VtxZ (-10.00, 10.00)/charged; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/FB: 16; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/eff/eta_phi.pdf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
l.10 \end{frame}

? 

! Package luatex.def Error: File `plots/task-1/ABC123_/qa_pt:0.20-2.00/VtxZ (
-10.00, 10.00)/charged; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/FB: 16; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/eff/eta_phi
.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

See the luatex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \end{frame}

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
l.10 \end{frame}

?
```

Comment: I've cleaned up the comment thread here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in pdflatex but fails in the lua part of luatex's inclusion (this must be the most crazy filename ever seen:-)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics{"plots/task-1/ABC123_/qa_pt:0.20-2.00/VtxZ (-10.00, 10.00)/charged; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/FB: 16; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/eff/eta_phi".pdf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

This version works in lualatex and pdflatex

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics{eta_phi.pdf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

To ensure the file is found prepend the plots directory to the input path for example this commandline works:

```
 TEXINPUTS=./plots//: lualatex mainfile
```

as (assuming bash shell) this locally sets TEXINPUTS to search all directories under `plots`

---

If you really have painted yourself into a corner with duplicated filenames in "interesting" directory paths then this does work in lualatex

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\Gread@@pdftex#1{%
  \edef\Gin@attr@hash{%
    \ifx\Gin@pagebox\@empty
    \else
      :\Gin@pagebox
    \fi
    \ifx\Gin@page\@empty
    \else
      :P\Gin@page
    \fi
    \ifx\Gin@decode\@empty\else
      :D[\Gin@decode]%
    \fi
    \ifGin@interpolate
      :I%
    \fi
  }%
  \@ifundefined{#1 image\Gin@attr@hash}%
    {%
      \saveimageresource
        \ifnum0%
          \ifx\Gin@decode\@empty\else 1\fi
          \ifGin@interpolate 1\fi
          >0 %
          attr{%
            \ifx\Gin@decode\@empty\else/Decode[\Gin@decode]\fi
            \ifGin@interpolate/Interpolate true\fi
          }%
        \fi
        \ifx\Gin@page\@empty\else page \Gin@page\fi
        \Gin@pagebox
        {\expandafter\zz#1}%
      \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\useimageresource\lastsavedimageresourceindex}%
      \def\Gin@llx{0}\let\Gin@lly\Gin@llx
      \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@urx{\wd\@tempboxa}%
      \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@ury{\ht\@tempboxa}%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname #1 image\Gin@attr@hash\endcsname
        {\useimageresource\the\lastsavedimageresourceindex}%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname #1 height\Gin@attr@hash\endcsname
        {\the\ht\@tempboxa}%
      \expandafter\xdef\csname #1 width\Gin@attr@hash\endcsname
        {\the\wd\@tempboxa}%
      \Gin@log{%
        <#1, %
        id=\the\lastsavedimageresourceindex, %
        \ifx\Gin@page\@empty\else page=\Gin@page , \fi
        \ifx\Gin@pagebox\@empty\else\ifx\Gin@pagebox\GPT@cropbox\else
          pagebox=\Gin@pagebox , \fi\fi
        \ifx\Gin@decode\@empty\else decode=[\Gin@decode], \fi
        \ifGin@interpolate interpolate=true, \fi
        \the\wd\@tempboxa\GPT@space x \the\ht\@tempboxa
        >%
      }%
    }{%
      \def\Gin@llx{0}\let\Gin@lly\Gin@llx
      \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@urx{\csname #1 width\Gin@attr@hash\endcsname}%
      \Gin@defaultbp\Gin@ury{\csname #1 height\Gin@attr@hash\endcsname}%
    }%
}

\def\zz"#1"{#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \includegraphics{"plots/task-1/ABC123_/qa_pt:0.20-2.00/VtxZ (-10.00, 10.00)/charged; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/FB: 16; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/eff/eta_phi".pdf}
%    \includegraphics{eta_phi.pdf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is really cool that it works in pdflatex, but what should I do when it will fail due to pgfplots with dozens of plots? As for TEXINPUTS, I have multiple such files under the `./plots/` tree.

Comment: @Latexsucks (a) you should consider changing your user name if you want people to help, it's not particularly polite and (b) the version I posted will work if you have thousands of files under `plots` why does that matter, so long as they have distinct names.

Comment: I won't be able to change my name until 6th of April, because I've changed it after I've asked this question.

Comment: @Latexsucks well as I say it's a disincentive for people to help, but up to you.

Comment: I have multiple files with this name. Changing it is not an option. pgfplots is fine with such paths.

Comment: @Latexsucks see update

Comment: @Latexsucks note that `\zz` macro unconditionally removes `"` (needed for tex) before passing the filename to Lua, which means that you have to use `"` in the input, a full production version would be more careful and only remove `"` if they were there.

Answer (score 1):

To include the file, write in your preable

```
\makeatletter
\def\Gin@getbase#1{%
  \edef\Gin@base{\filename@area\filename@base}%
  \edef\Gin@ext{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

This should be a last resort. I *strongly* recommend finding a way to use saner filenames instead.

**EDIT**: With this, the whole file should look like

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610,10pt]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\def\Gin@getbase#1{%
  \edef\Gin@base{\filename@area\filename@base}%
  \edef\Gin@ext{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics{plots/task-1/ABC123_/qa_pt:0.20-2.00/VtxZ (-10.00, 10.00)/charged; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/FB: 16; eta (-0.80, 0.80)/eff/eta_phi.pdf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should I use braces/quotes around the file name with your solution?

Comment: No, that should not be necessary.

Comment: I've included your code after `\documentclass` and before `\begin{document}` and I get `! Missing $ inserted.`

Comment: did you test this with luatex on the suggested filename?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did, it works on my system. I just updated my TeXLive, so maybe it doesn't work with older packages?

Comment: I did the same you do in **EDIT**. I still have the errors. I've run `latexmk -c` to make sure I don't have any aux files.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I was using texlive 2018 pretest, updated today (but get the same `$` error with tl2017)

Comment: Then I don't know what is going on. @DavidCarlisle Do you think I should delete the answer?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger no keep it, but I was probing as I will probably make spaces work by default at some point and edge cases are good tests... It might be OS dependent as it relates to how tex and lua file searching reacts to the weird filenames. I was using cygwin (so a virtual linux-ish filesystem sitting over windows) chances are that you were not...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Right, I tested it on a (real) ArchLinux

Comment: I've tested on a (real) Ubuntu 17.10 with TeXLive 20170818 from official Ubuntu repositories. And, as I've told, I have the same error as in question.